# Can't detect click event in ng-click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, svg

I want to detect a click event on a `SVG` element, or more precisely on a `g` element inside a `SVG` element.

What I have so far is this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9af2y019/1/)

The `ng-click`fires fine but the `click` event doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should **load jQuery** library if you want use `$` or `angular.element('selector')` in you example on JSFiddle.

Second you should run `$scope.$apply()` if you use external library to handle event.

Worked example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9af2y019/2/)

Comment: Sorry about that, was a bit to quick. thank you ;-)

The initial problem I had is still there thou. When you click the `svg` the second field isn't set to true, unless you click it again

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard ok, I have updated my solution on JSFiddle, I belive now it what you want :)

Comment: Almost. The problem is if I where to have two `svg`s and I only wanted to detect clicks on the one nested inside the `ng-click` your solution here allows all `g` elements to allow the variable to be true

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard why you don't put ng-click on interesting `g` tag so?


http://content.screencast.com/users/maksimrv/folders/Jing/media/46db5469-7242-45f8-a9f3-2f2c3d609c85/00000332.png

Comment: I can't, in the example I have added the `svg` manually, but in the final version I'm getting it from an unknown source

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard do you want handle click on specific `g` tag or handle click on all `g` tags inside specific `svg` tag?

Comment: on `g` tags inside a specific `svg` tag

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard ok what about something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/9af2y019/12/?